# How exactly does xmlstarlet move work

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I want to move around elements in an xml document with `xmlstarlet`

Specifically I want to make the following changes

```
<parent>
    <before/>
    <span><a>blah</a></span>
    <after/>  
<parent>
<otherparent>
    <span><a>blah</a></span>
<otherparent>
```

becomes ..

```
<parent>
    <before/>
    <a>blah</a>
    <after/>
</parent>
<otherparent>
    <a>blah</a>
</otherparent>
```

I.e delete span but keep the children.

[xmlstarlet has a move command: xmlstart ed -m source target](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) but I don't really understand how it works.

It takes a source and a target xpath but I don't really understand how these get matched up because they can result in sets of different sizes. Is the target relative to the source?

Comment: add more context/parent structure - it should be shown where the resulting `<a>blah</a>` is located/inserted. Post the structure with parent nodes

Comment: I don't feel that this is particularly relevant. I want delete *all spans*  while keeping their content. This is really just an example to motivate the question.

Comment: you don't understand, the crucial child nodes should be moved in right places in case if spans are in arbitrary order within xml document.

Comment: Ah I understand... the problem isn't completely specified without other children. I guess I want it to "stay correct location?"

Comment: For ex. `<div><span id="1"><span><a>blah</a></span></span></div><div></div><div><span id="2"><span><a>blah</a></span></span></div>`

Comment: Okay I've added some more edge cases to my "test input and output"

Answer (score 1):

Complex **xmlstarlet** solution:

Input xml file `test.xml`:

```
<div>
  <parent>
    <before/>
    <span>
      <a>value 1</a>
    </span>
    <after/>
  </parent>
  <otherparent>
    <span>
      <a>value 2</a>
    </span>
  </otherparent>
</div>
```

---

The job:

```
count=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//span[a])' test.xml)
for ((i=1; i<=$count; i++)); do 
    xmlstarlet ed -L -a '(//span[a])[1]' -t elem -n "a" -v "$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "(//span/a)[1]" 1.xml)" -d '(//span[a])[1]' test.xml
done
```

---

- `count` - variable containing the number of `span` nodes which have child `a` node
- `ed` - edit mode
- `-L` - modify the file inplace
- `-a` - append action
- `-d` - delete action

---

The final `test.xml` (after processing):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div>
  <parent>
    <before/>
    <a>value 1</a>
    <after/>
  </parent>
  <otherparent>
    <a>value 2</a>
  </otherparent>
</div>
```